# Whe does my XCeed DataGridControl with IValueConverter always returns 0 for a null value?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, xceed

I have a WPF application with an XCeed DataGridControl.
I'm trying to use an IValueConverter to convert a data cell (int? value)'s contents as follows.

```
If value == null or non-numeric then display 'N/A'
If value is numeric then display the value.
```

I'm binding the grid to an ObservableCollection of this class:

```
public class SampleClass 
{
public int? SampleNullableIntValue { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my value converter:

```
  public class NumericNullConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        private bool IsNumber(object value)
        {
            return value is sbyte
                    || value is byte
                    || value is short
                    || value is ushort
                    || value is int
                    || value is uint
                    || value is long
                    || value is ulong
                    || value is float
                    || value is double
                    || value is decimal;
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
                             object parameter, 
                             System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return parameter;
            }

            if (IsNumber(value))
            {
                var num = System.Convert.ToInt64(value);
                if (num != 0L)
                {
                    return value;
                }
            }
            return parameter;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(
              object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
               System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Here is my Data Template Definition:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NumericNullContentTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource
             NumericNullOrZeroConvert}, ConverterParameter='N/A'}" TextAlignment="Center" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Here is my XCeed DataGridControl definition, with the DataGridColumn using the above defined template:

```
 <xcdg:DataGridControl> 
  <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
     <xcdg:Column SampleNullableIntValue Title="SampleTitle" 
    CellContentTemplate="{StaticResource NumericNullContentTemplate}" 
    Width="100"/>
   </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
 </xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

I cannot get this to behave correctly.
Instead of return 'N/A' for the case of null values, grid ALWAYS displays a zero (0). The Converter returns 'N/A' as expected when it encounters NULL
I've tested the converter independent of XCeed and it works as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?
Is there an issue/bug with XCeed?

Thanks,JohnB

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have the column binding correct, though I admit I haven't used the Xceed DataGrid for a long time. In any case I downloaded the latest version (v6.6) and the code you've shown won't even compile for me. Particularly how you've specified `SampleNullableIntValue` as a parameter for the Column control.

Adding a `FieldName` and specifying `SampleNullableIntValue` in the `DisplayMemberBindingInfo` seems to work though:

```
<xcdg:Column Title="SampleTitle" FieldName="NullableIntValue"
             CellContentTemplate="{StaticResource NumericNullContentTemplate}"
             Width="100">
    <xcdg:Column.DisplayMemberBindingInfo>
        <xcdg:DataGridBindingInfo Path="SampleNullableIntValue"/>
    </xcdg:Column.DisplayMemberBindingInfo>
</xcdg:Column>
```

of course this is assuming you collection is setup correctly and correctly assigned as the DataGrid's `DataContext`.

Comment: My bad, fat finger on typing in example. IN real App I have FieldName specified. I'll try using DataGridBindingInfo and see if that helps.